# How to apply drop caps in verse environment in memoir class?

Tags: memoir, lettrine, verse

I'm typesetting poetry using the `memoir` class and I'm trying to have each poem start with a drop capital (using the `lettrine` package), but it doesn't fit nicely and there is considerable overlap:

[image: mwe]

How can I fix this? I would like to have the second line to be aligned with the drop cap as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\PoemTitle{}
\begin{verse}
\lettrine{L}{et} me not to the marriage of true minds \\
Admit impediments. Love is not love \\
Which alters when it alteration finds \\
Or bends with the remover to remove.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: forced lines in verse and similar environments are (internally) separate paragraphs so lettrine making later lines in the paragraph cut in doesn't work as each paragraph is one line. It's probably fixable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be possible to patch `lettine` to understand the internal paragraph structure being used here, but simpler is to define a simpler version that just works in this case, requiring exactly one fixed `\\`  line break in the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newbox\xlet

\def\xlettrine#1#2#3\\{%
\sbox\xlet{\HUGE\bfseries #1}%
\smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\usebox\xlet}}%
\textsc{#2}%
#3\\%
\makebox[\wd\xlet]{}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\PoemTitle{}
\begin{verse}
\xlettrine{L}{et} me not to the marriage of true minds \\
Admit impediments. Love is not love \\
Which alters when it alteration finds \\
Or bends with the remover to remove.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix. But how would one would patch lettrine for this purpose?

Comment: @SanthoshKumaran I wouldn't. whatever layout you want it would be easier to implement directly as shown here

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you let the drop-cap "L" protrude into the verse's left-hand margin, by making use of the `ante` option. Makes for a doubly-snazzy look...

And, since there's a visual void to the upper-right of the letter "L", I'd also use an option such as `findent=-4pt` to "snug up" the following letters to the drop-cap letter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\PoemTitle{}
\begin{verse}
\lettrine[ante=\kern-48pt,findent=-4pt]{L}{et me not} 
     to the marriage of true minds \\
Admit impediments. Love is not love \\
Which alters when it alteration finds \\
Or bends with the remover to remove.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```